# Export jProfiler reports

Tags: jprofiler

Someone sent me a jprofiler report but I do not have it and I do not plan to purchase it. They are having some trouble understanding this. Does jProfiler allow users to export reports in text/html/pdf/etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all views can be exported as HTML, XML or CSV.